# Where did HashSet<T> go in VS2012?

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2012, hashset

I recently installed VS2012.  A C++ project (with .Net 4.0) that compiles fine under VS2010 is not recognizing `HashSet<T>` on VS2012.  I even tried being explicit with following declaration:

```
System::Collections::Generic::HashSet< String^ >^ _reasons;
```

But that only results in the error:

```
error C2039: 'HashSet' : is not a member of 'System::Collections::Generic
```

The documentation says it's in System.Collections.Generic.  The C++ compiler doesn't think so.

Any ideas on where it went?

Comment: *A C++ project (with .Net 4.0)* Ouch. In **normal** C++, there is `unordered_set`.

Comment: Do you have assembly `System.Core` referenced? The System::Collections::Generic namespace exists in several assemblies, you'd get that error message if you reference one of them, but not the one that includes HashSet.

Comment: Explicitly added System.Core as a reference.  That fixed it.  Thanks David!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HashSet<> was a late addition to .NET, it became available in .NET 3.5.  The namespace is older, mscorlib.dll contained classes in System::Collections::Generic since .NET 2.0, classes like Stack<> and Queue<>.  HashSet<> got added in a *new* assembly for .NET 3.5, System.Core.dll, they didn't want to tinker with the 2.0 assemblies.

Accordingly, you must add a reference to System.Core to avoid the error message.

Always refer back to the MSDN documentation when you get an error like this, it shows you want assembly reference is required.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  It didn't occur to me that I would need to add a new reference since I didn't change the .Net framework I was compiling against.  Now I know.

Comment: Well, you did actually.  You changed the target from 2.0 to 3.5, the only version that has System.Core.  The C++ IDE isn't that sophisticated about it like the C# or VB.NET IDEs.  Pretty typical about C++ tooling, it assumes you know what you are doing.

Comment: Great Answer, but to help out other new c++ people like me, this is what my reference looked like to fix it: #using <System.Core.dll>